# Getting "typeError" "is not a function" when using .length

Tags: javascript

Here is my code:

```js
function permAlone(string) {
  if (string.length < 2) return string; // This is our break condition

  var permutations = []; // This array will hold our permutations

  for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    var character = string[i];

    // Cause we don't want any duplicates:
    if (string.indexOf(character) != i) // if char was used already
      continue; // skip it this time

    var remainingString = string.slice(0, i) + string.slice(i + 1, string.length); //Note: you can concat Strings via '+' in JS

    for (var subPermutation of permAlone(remainingString))
      permutations.push(character + subPermutation);

  }

  var permutationsFinal = [];
  for (var j = 0; j < (permutations.length); j++) {
    if (!(permutations[j].match(/([a-zA-Z])\1/))) {
      permutationsFinal.push(permutations[j]);
    }
  }

  return (permutationsFinal.length);
  //                       ^^^^^^^^ if I add this, the error is thrown
}

permAlone('abc');
```

If I replace:

```
return (permutationsFinal);
```

by:

```
return (permutationsFinal.length);
```

I get this error in the console:

> TypeError: `permAlone` is not a function

**Why?**

Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: My guess: It is a recursive function, if you return anything other than what is expected by the function itself then you will break the recursive loop. I only say guess because I am not 100% sure what you are trying to do.

Comment: Ah crap!  You're so right! I forgot about that part!  I need to divide this function in two different functions. Thanks for your help!

Comment: That's so weird, I didn't even know that would happen. Good question!

Comment: @Aduss You should write that as an answer so Emilio can accept it.

Comment: `for (var subPermutation of permAlone(remainingString))` iterates over the return value of the function (called recursively). It's the line number of the error. Numbers are not iterable, so when you return a number instead of an array it throws an error. On that line number. No mystery.

Comment: @Traktor53 Well it said `permAlone is not a function` and I was stumped. I wouldn't have known that error meant I needed to check what I was trying to iterate over. Then again I don't often use `for-of`.

Comment: Okay, I had help. Firefox reports the errror as "TypeError: permAlone(...) is not iterable" which is meaningful. Downvote removed. And Ill post it as an answer.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir You made the code a snippet but it does nothing in its current state. I'd recommend changing the last line to `console.log(permAlone('abc'));`

Comment: Note that the brackets in `return (permutationsFinal)` do nothing useful.

Comment: @Clonkex, Done, although a bit late to the party I guess.

Comment: @Clonkex fixed. I just left the code as is in the first edition. The problem is explained bellow so anyone can just copy it and add the `.length` and check for themselves.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Nice, that makes me much happier :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a recursive function, if you return anything other than what is expected by the function itself then you will break the recursive loop.

Answer (score 3):

To remove an answer from comment:

`for (var subPermutation of permAlone(remainingString))` iterates over the return value of the function (called recursively). It's the line number of the error. Numbers are not iterable, so when you return a number instead of an array it throws an error.

Not sure what browser you are using, but FireFox reports the error as

> > TypeError: permAlone(...) is not iterable

which is more or less self explanatory. If the error message reported in your browser is for the code posted, it is arguably not just misleading but factually incorrect.

Comment: Just so it is known, chrome create the same error the OP described: permAlone is not a function